# Qt foreach is giving me sytax error highlight in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt

Qt foreach is giving me sytax error highlight in Eclipse.

I'm programming in C++ using a Qt framework.

I use Eclipse SDK (3.5.2) as my text editor / IDE.

I compile in a console outside of Eclipse using GCC.

When I'm editing my files in Eclipse, I find that Qt's "foreach" is highlighting as a syntax error.

Does anyone know how to fix this?  It's not majorly important or anything but it's starting to annoy me.  It's as though it's not recognizing the command or something...

Comment: It's the same with boost's foreach. I disabled the squiggly lines, but it would be cool if eclipse could parse the foreach macro.

Comment: You are using Qt, why not just move to Qt Creator, which is (imho) far better than Eclipse?

Comment: I think its defined in `<QtGlobal>` try including it to hint the IDE.

Comment: I prefer Eclipse.  Also I'd rather not add unnecessary includes to potentially solve a local visual issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you've enable c++11 support in Eclipse you can redefine 'foreach' to be a range based for loop.  In the project properties, select 'Paths and Symbols' in the left pane, then select the 'Symbols' tab.  Add a new symbol with 'Name'= foreach(a,b) 'Value'=for(a:b) Select 'Add to all configurations' and 'Add to all languages'

Answer (score 0):

foreach is not a standard C++ keyword. I think the Qt moc compiler transforms this to generated code, like it does with signals/slots in Q_OBJECT tagged classes.
So it's to be expected that Eclipse fails to recognize this.
If you use these Qt-specific features, you're better off using Qt creator.

Comment: I agree with your reply but the question was how to fix it. I'm sure by changing the Eclipse preferences it is possible not to show a syntax error for the foreach procedure.